# Animating display of items in ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-animation

[image]

I have a listview with a custom adapter. So far, I have achieved the functionality on the first "screen".

Now, I want to add a detail tab about each item, which pushes the members beneath it to get space.
How to animate the push down, so it has a smooth transition?

Comment: You would need to create another activity/fragment that has a layout which would have fields for the item details. Implement on-click functionality that makes transitions between screens or replaces the current fragment with the detail fragment. Hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom adapter, in the getView() method, you can set onClickListener for the view, which contains the whole row. Then you have options to implement the animation for showing/hiding the other views when the user clicks.

Sliding a View down by a distance

```
view.animate().translationY(distance);
```

You can later slide the View back to its original position like this:

```
view.animate().translationY(0);
```

You can also easily combine multiple animations. The following animation will slide a View down by its height and fade it in at the same time:

```
// Prepare the View for the animation
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.setAlpha(0.0f);

// Start the animation
view.animate()
    .translationY(view.getHeight())
    .alpha(1.0f);
```

You can then fade the View back out and slide it back to its original position. We also set an AnimatorListener so we can set the visibility of the View back to GONE once the animation is finished:

```
view.animate()
    .translationY(0)
    .alpha(0.0f)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **ExpandableListView** instead **ListView**.

Look this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Hope it help!

Comment: And if you want a cleaner look, you can disable some of it's GUI components like :  android:groupIndicator.

Answer (score 0):

**Your list_selector.xml file in Drawable Folder**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector
        android:id="@+id/myselector"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item
          android:state_activated="false"
          android:drawable="#C9C9C9" />

    </selector>
```

**List View in**

**android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_drawer"**

```
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#d2d1d1"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_drawer"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
```

**Working**